# Add jquery drag and drop in prestashop module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm new in prestashop and i try to add jquery Ui for drag and drop in prestashop.

i find that i need to add in my controller this line:

```
 $this->addJqueryUI(array(
        'ui.drop',
        'ui.drag'
    ));
```

but it didn't work .

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names are wrong. Here are the correct names.

```
$this->addJqueryUI(array(
    'ui.draggable',
    'ui.droppable' 
));
```